# Can't access this.$store (vuex) in any child component after basic installation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

So I am totally new to vuex. I carefully install the vuex to my vue app but I can't acess the this.$store in any of my child component.

I have also read more than 10 questions ask the same thing and I did a lot of changes, tried lots of times. Since I thought I did everything right and it still doesn't work. I finally decide to come here and ask. I will put my own codes below:

**file structure (only related files):**

```
|---main.js
|---store.js
|---App.vue
|---components
```

**main.js:**

```
import '@babel/polyfill'
import Vue from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue'

import './plugins/vuetify'
import './plugins/vue-resource'
import { store } from './store';

require('../node_modules/ol/ol.css');

Vue.config.productionTip = false

fetch('static/App_Config.json')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json().then(function (AppConfig) {
      Vue.prototype.$AppConfig = AppConfig;

      new Vue({
        store,
        render: h => h(App)
      }).$mount('#app')

    });
  })
```

**store.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex, {
});

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        testText: "test string"
    }
});
```

**in components: (simplified, only related codes)**

```
<script>
    created () {
        console.log("this.$store_test: ", this.$store);
    }
</script>
```

---

**I have already tried these possibilties:**

1. in main.js:

use `import store from './store';` rather than `import { store } from './store';`

2. in main.js:

use `store: store`, rather than `store,`

3. in store.js:

use `Vue.use(Vuex);` rather than `Vue.use(Vuex, {});`

4. in store.js: (combined with 1. I have tried all 4 combinitions)

use `export default store = new Vuex.Store` rather than `export const store = new Vuex.Store`

5. put the console not in created hook, but in methods, and made a button to trigger it.
6. put the console in other child components, which nested in different deeps

**After I serched a lot similar qustions and tried a lot (also with 20+ time server restart). I still can get this.$store. I kind of need some help.**

**I DO NOT think this question is duplicate, because I have already read other questions and tried all the possiblities. If they all failed, it must be something new here with mine codes.**

Comment: FYI, it's best to list the other questions you've looked at and if possible, explain why / how they didn't work for you. It helps avoid this getting prematurely closed as a duplicate

Comment: What's happening? An error that `this.$store` is undefined?

Comment: If your _component_ example is trimmed down, could you at least show it as an actual component, eg `export default { created() { ... } }`. Otherwise, if your code is actually what you've got, then that's not how you write a component

Comment: @ceejayoz sorry thst I even forgot to mention that. I got exactly this.$store is undefined

Comment: @Phil sorry that I maybe cut the component too much. Yes they are all real components. I am actually not new to vue.js. Just need to use vuex because of another problem I have got (you can see it in my other questions, but it is not related to this qustion). They are all real components and my app works fine. Only the veux part is the problem so I asked this question

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score -1):

This is a valid Vuex `store.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        testText: "test string";
    }
});

export default store;
```

Remember to create a `getter`, `mutation` and `action` for your variables in Vuex, you should **not** handle the state directly.

It doesn't matter in `main.js` if you use `store` or `store: store`, they are identical.

`import store from './store'` is the same as `import { store } from './store'`.

`Vue.use(Vuex)` and `Vue.use(Vuex, {})` are the same as long as you don't supply any options.

You don't need to get the store in a component somewhere, you're loading Vuex before the app is mounted, so you can actually start using it in e.g. the `main.js` created hook.

Your components `<script>` tag is incorrect. You should use `export default`, like this:

```
<script>
export default {
    created () {
        // Check if console.log like this works better as well
        console.log("Store test:");
        console.log(this.$store);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `import store from './store'` is **NOT** the same as `import { store } from './store'.` One is getting the entire object, one is destructuring.

Comment: Let me clarify then, it's unrelated to the problem whether you use `store` or `{ store }`

Comment: His export is defined as this `export const store`. `import store from "./store"` will not work. Your answer is not related to the problem either, it doesn't answer anything.

Comment: Then you didn't read the question nor my answer properly if that's what you think.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with his store definition. I'm thinking it's the `fetch` part, but then again I've never done `Vue.use` inside a `fetch`